# He bought the same car as me

Tags: sentence-structure

Is it correct to say

> Dilbert bought the same car as me.

If it is, what are other sentences for other pronouns such as he?

> Dilbert bought the same car as David/he/him

I know you can say

> Dilbert bought the same car as yours

when you refer to or compare objects.

Comment: You might find [this column](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/the-basics-on-subject-and-object-pronouns-b/) helpful.

Comment: @J.R. This question is about more the usage of "the same ...as" than " object or subject pronouns". Thank you for the link though.

Comment: You should probably edit your question, then, and make that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You could say either

> Dilbert bought the same car as **me**.
>   Dilbert bought the same car as **mine**.

and it would be understood that you both have the same car.

You could also say

> Dilbert bought the same car as **David**.
>   Dilbert bought the same car as **him**. *(that guy over there)*.
>   Dilbert bought the same car as **his** *(car)*.

depending on the context and where you want to place emphasis, and all three would be understood to mean they bought have the same car.

Comment: I confused because I am only familiar to the structure of the second sentence in your answer. However, when I use "him" or "David", I feel the focus of sentence becomes who did and what did he do such as  "David bought a car and Dilbert also bought the same car."  In this case we should able to say that "Dilbert bought the same car as David's"  but I am not sure.

Comment: @Mrt  Yes you can say that because it's the final car that is understood, "Dilbert bought the same car as David's *(car)*."